# Conversion of HEX string to EBCDIC returns Number Format exception

Tags: java, string, utf-8, hex

I am trying to convert a string composed of hex data like `C120` which means `A` and  (space) respectively. I am getting the string and trying to split it into array of string. I am then trying to iterate this array and get the corresponding `UTF-8` values. Below is my code:

```
public static String toEbcdic(String strToConvert){
    String[] test = strToConvert.split("(?<=\\G..)");
    ByteBuffer sb = ByteBuffer.allocate(test.length);
    for (String s : test) {
        Byte valueOf = Byte.valueOf(s, 10);
        sb.put(valueOf);
    }
    return new String(sb.array(), "CP1047");
}
```

When passed the input `C120C2`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C1"
```

What am I doing wrong? What should be done to get the corresponding EBCDIC value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple one-liner:

```
public static String toEbcdic( String hexStr ) throws IOException {
   return new String( DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary( hexStr ), "CP1047" );
}
```

---

Your code is in the right direction, by converting to byte array and create a new String in CP1047.
You only need to fix two issues to get it working:

1. The byte string is in hex (base 16) instead of dec (base 10).
2. Java byte is signed, so feeding it C1 would triggers an "Value out of range" exception. 
    Solution is simple: parse as short and cast back to byte.

Here is a complete fixed example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Q45235042 {

   public static String toEbcdic( String strToConvert ) throws IOException {
      String[] test = strToConvert.split( "(?<=\\G..)" );
      ByteBuffer sb = ByteBuffer.allocate( test.length );
      for ( String s : test )
         sb.put( (byte) Short.parseShort( s, 16 ) );
      return new String( sb.array(), "CP1047");
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      System.out.println( toEbcdic( "C120C2" ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: You have saved me after one week of toiling. Wish it had happened before. Thanks! I never though of going to short and then byte. But the one liner is awesome. Thanks again! Unfortunately the bounty can be awarded after 20 hours from now so I will do it once it crosses the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hex is base 16 not base 10. Change

```
Byte valueOf = Byte.valueOf(s, 10);
```

to

```
Byte valueOf = Byte.valueOf(s, 16);
```

**or** use [`Byte.parseByte(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-) to get the primitive type (instead of the wrapper).

```
byte valueOf = Byte.parseByte(s, 16);
```

Comment: I am not trying to convert it to hex but the ebcdic value.

Comment: No. You are trying to convert a hex value to binary. And "c" isn't a valid digit in decimal.

Comment: Okay then how do I convert a string of hex to ebcdic representation?